# select-string with dynamical context parameter value

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I want to perform some log analyses. Example log file listed below. I know how to resolve this issue with procedure/script, but I wonder how it can be done in 'powershell style' with pipelines etc

Log file contains from string with filename and list of components. Each of them can be 'passed' or 'failed'. I want to print all lines starting with 'Checking' which has at least one FAILED component.

---

```
Checking : C:\TFS\Datavarehus\Main\ETL\SSIS\DVH Project\APL_STG1_Daglig_Master.dtsx

Checking : C:\TFS\Datavarehus\Main\ETL\SSIS\DVH Project\COPY_STG1_APL_Dekningsgrupper_Z1.dtsx
    SQLCommand [Z1 APL_Dekningsgrupper] FAILED the VA1 check (table name as source)
    SQLCommand [APL_Dekningsgrupper] passed the VA1 check
    SQLCommand [FAK_Avkastningsgaranti_Kollektiv] FAILED the VA1 check (table name as source)

Checking : C:\TFS\Datavarehus\Main\ETL\SSIS\DVH Project\DM_DVH_BpBedrift_InvesterteFond 1.dtsx
    SQLCommand [DVH] passed the VA1 check
    SQLCommand [Avtale Kurs] passed the VA1 check
```

---

At the glance looks like I need something similar to

```
gc logtxt | select-string -pattern 'FAILED' -context <nearest line starting with "Checking" in begining direction>,<lines count from CheckingLine to "LineWith 'FAILED'">
```

Comment: Is there an empty line between every "Checking"-entry or did you put the empty line there just to have cleaner code?

Answer (score 2):

A crude version:

```
$line = $null
gc test.txt | %{ 
    if($line){ 
        if($_ -match "FAILED"){
            $line
            $line = $null
        }
    }
    if($_ -match "^Checking"){
        $line = $_
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for tips. Finally I got following working code:

```
gc test.txt | Foreach {
    if ($_.StartsWith('Checking'))  {
        $pkname = $_
    }
    if ($_.Contains('FAILED')) { 
        if (!($pkname.equals($printed_pkname))) {
        $pkname; 
        $printed_pkname=$pkname} 
        $_ }
    }
```